# Correct way of checking if a ICollection is actually read-only

Tags: c#

There is my model class

```
public class Model 
{
    public ICollection<string> MyCollection { get; }
}
```

I want to test `MyCollection` getter returns an **actual** read-only collection. That is clients of the class can neither add nor remove elements to/from it at all. What's the correct way to write such test?

**Option 1**

```
Assert.That(modelInstance.MyCollection is IReadonlyCollection<string>);
```

It's returns true e.g when field of the `MyCollection` property is an instance of `List<string>` (it implements `IReadonlyCollection<string>`).

**Option 2**

```
var testDelegate = () => modelInstance.MyCollection.Add("QWERTY");
Assert.That(testDelegate, Throws.TypeOf<NotSupportedException>());
```

I find it not elegant since probably there are other ways to modificate a returned collection (such as indexers for `List<string>`)

So is changing of type of the property to `ReadOnlyCollection<string>` the only solution to achieve needed behavior? At that case I do need any unit tests but it does the type of the `MyCollection` more specific.

Comment: A `List<T>` _is_ an actual `IReadonlyCollection<T>` though

Comment: @maccettura: isn't it what OP has said in his question? _"It returns true e.g when field of the MyCollection property is an instance of List<string> (it implements IReadonlyCollection<string>)."_

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes, I am just curious why it returning true is a bad thing.  You are checking if something is a `IReadOnlyCollection`, and a `List` _is_ an `IReadOnlyCollection`, why is `true` a bad value?

Comment: @maccettura: Because "implementing IReadonlyCollection` isn't the same as "clients of the class can neither add nor remove elements to/from it at all". It's an unfortunate name, IMO.

Comment: @maccettura: because he doesnt want to know if it implements that interface, he wants to know if the collection cannot be modified.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ICollection` offers a property called [`IsReadOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cfatk9t(v=vs.110).aspx) that lets you check that your collection instance is read-only without doing any tricks:

```
Assert.That(modelInstance.MyCollection.IsReadonly);
```

Comment: I can understand the reasons for `List<T>` imlemementing `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, but it still a bit confuse me that for a `List<T>` instance `(list as ICollection<string>).IsReadOnly == false`  and `(list is IReadOnlyCollection<string>) == true` simultaneously

Comment: @Mergasov This is a naming problem in the collection API: `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` should be named `IReadAccessCollection<T>` or something along these lines, because "Only" is absolutely wrong there. I understand why they added `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` interface to `List<T>`, but as you noted, it gives a completely wrong impression.

Answer (score 0):

dasblinkenlight answered your question directly: use `IsReadOnly`. Your other question is a good one too:

> So is changing of type of the property to `ReadOnlyCollection<string>` the only solution to achieve needed behavior?

It's not the only solution, but I think it is the best one.

You **should** declare your property as `IReadOnlyCollection<string>` if that is what the collection is. The API of your classes or interfaces should describe how they should be used, and let me know (as a consumer of your code) how to expect them to behave.

For example, it's a bad code smell to have an `IList<string>` property but throw an exception whenever items are added or removed. If you're modeling a read-only collection, be explicit and use `IReadOnlyCollection<string>` if you can.

Your example is a bit more subtle, but when you see things like checking whether an interface method will throw `NotSupportedException`, it's a good hint to make sure the interface is properly describing the behavior of your class.

Comment: I agree with you and intend to change the type of the property to `IReadOnlyCollection<string>`, but this type is not guarantee a **actual** collection (from the field) is read-only, since (e.g) `List<string>` implements that interface. In the other hand `ReadOnlyCollection<string>` (not interface) is hard-coded type in my opinion

Comment: "_it's a bad code smell to have an IList<string> property but throw an exception whenever items are added or removed_" I agree, but it's an unfortunate code smell that one might have to tolerate. I do recommend implementing ICollection<T>/IList<T> even for read-only list types when these types will potentially be used with Linq, for example. Because, Linq has an optimized (faster) execution path for ICollection<T>/IList<T>, but not for IReadOnlyList<T>. It's a sad state affair still today, sadly (https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/42254) Choose your poison: smelly code or poor Linq perf.

Comment: @EyesShriveledToRaisins Good to know, and thanks for linking to the runtime repo. I hadn't seen that before.